# Compare a table column between MYSQL and SQL Server to get the difference

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, oop

I need to compare a table column coming from two different type of databases(MYSQL and SQL Server) in php.

For the background the table column that i need to compare doesn't have the same values so i am converting them first for proper comparison e.g value in MYSQL is BN014 which is equivalent to BN00000014 in SQl Server (just extra 4 to 5 zeros after first two characters). I am using the following function for the required conversion, this part seems to be working fine:

```
function convertWR($wr)
{
    $mysqli=$this->con;
    $wr_number =  $wr;
    $prod_zeros='';
    $p_cat=substr($wr_number,0,2);
    $p_num=substr($wr_number,2,strlen($wr_number)-2);
    $p_num_len=strlen($p_num);
    $ctrl=8;
    while ($ctrl>$p_num_len){
        $prod_zeros.="0";
        $ctrl--;
    }

    $converted_id=$p_cat.$prod_zeros.$p_num;
    return $converted_id;

}
```

For the comparison part i am storing the results from both databases in separate arrays named $wr_from_mssql and $wr_from_mysql respectively, then comparing them using the function array_diff():

```
function compareData()
{
 //SQL Server data   
  $mssql=$this->mssql;
  if($mssql)
    {
        //echo "connected";
      if(($result = sqlsrv_query($mssql,"SELECT [ItemId] FROM [dbo].[Item]")) !== false)
      {
          $count_mssql=1;          
          $wr_from_mssql=array();

          while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result ))
          {
              $clean_itemid=$string = str_replace(' ', '', $obj['ItemId']);
              $wr_from_mssql[]=$clean_itemid;                
              $count_mssql++;
          }
     }


    }else {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
          }
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

    //MYSQL data
    $mysqli=$this->con;
    $count_mysql=1;
    $wr_from_mysql=array();
    $sql="SELECT WR FROM products";

    $result= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        //for the required conversion e.g BN014 to BN00000014 
        $wr= $this->dynacomWR($row['WR']);
        $clean_wr=$string = str_replace(' ', '', $wr);
        $wr_from_mysql[]=$clean_wr;            
        $count_mysql++;
    }

   //----------------------------------------------------------------------//
   //To get the difference
    $result=array_diff($wr_from_mssql,$wr_from_mysql);
    $count_diff=1;

    foreach($result as $diff)
    {
        echo  $count_diff.") ".$diff."</br>";
        $count_diff++;
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);        
    $result2=array_diff($result,$wr_from_mysql);   
    mysqli_close($mysqli);

}
```

However i am not getting the expected results, I am still getting 3000+ values that exists in both tables. I am expecting around 7000 results while getting 10,000++ .

There are no white spaces or regular spaces(though i still tried removing them) that could affect this comparison as we do clean the strings before inserting them to our tables.

Any idea what could be going wrong, any other possible method for this type of comparison? need it for a report so cannot use the free tools available.

Comment: Why are you doing this in code?  Why not just set up a linked server and do the work in SQL?

Comment: Hi Gordon, because values from MYSQL have to be converted in order to match their counterparts in SQL Server e.g BN014 to BN00000014. Please refer to the first coding part of my question for more details. However i got an idea from your suggestion so i am going to create a new table with converted values and then use it with linked server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best approach as suggested by @GordonLinoff , but I was able to get the desired results :) by creating a temporary table with the converted values and then using the above code, off course with some modifications for mysql query to compare the column values between the new temporary table and the SQL Server table.

I was unable to use the linked server due to a network issue which i will resolve in future. Have some deadlines to meet.